# How do I use custom android.media.MediaDataSource along with android.media.MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, url-scheme

I know Android's `MediaPlayer` is a great thing. It allows us to play local files as well as media streams. And it is quite easy to use (just for example):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://streaming.shoutcast.com/80sPlanet"); // this steam broadcasts audio/mpeg
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

It is possible to set different types of DataSource by calling the overloaded `setDataSource()` with different set of parameters.
And there is an interesting prototype of this function:

```
void setDataSource(MediaDataSource dataSource)
```

Looks like it is possible to completely override the `DataSource` with your own implementation. And it works indeed:

```
import android.media.MediaDataSource;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class UrlMediaDataSource extends MediaDataSource {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    BufferedInputStream stream;

    public UrlMediaDataSource(URL url) throws IOException {
        this.url = url;
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int readAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) throws IOException {
        if (stream == null)
            stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        return stream.read(buffer, offset, size);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        stream.close();
        stream = null;
        connection.disconnect();
        connection = null;
    }
}
```

and in the main code:

```
UrlMediaDataSource dataSource = new UrlMediaDataSource(new URL("http://streaming.shoutcast.com/80sPlanet"));
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Yes, this works fine. But if I try audio/aacp broadcasting stream (for example: "http://111.223.51.8:8005" - it is "COOLfahrenheit 93" radio), the player does not play. Logcat trace:

```
06-07 23:26:01.680 1352-1147/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
06-07 23:26:01.681 1352-1093/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf3e051e0), (100, 1, -2147483648)
06-07 23:26:01.735 1352-2013/? D/NuPlayerDriver: reset(0xf3e051e0)
06-07 23:26:01.735 1352-2013/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xf3e051e0), (8, 0, 0)
06-07 23:26:01.736 1352-1093/? D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyResetComplete(0xf3e051e0)
```

Though, the URL works fine (the music plays) when no custom `MediaDataSource` is used:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://111.223.51.8:8005");
```

Does anybody know the right way to manage this?
Just don't propose me to use the `URL` directly - I need a custom `MediaDataSource` to get access to the raw data of the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The main point is that the `MediaPlayer` does playback **audio/mpeg** (both ways - through URL and through custom `MediaDataSource`), but **audio/aacp** streams could be played back only via URL as `DataSource`.

So, let's understand what's happening under the hoods.

When you are passing an URL as a data source, then [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#L1074) check is being performed:

```
    if ("file".equals(scheme)) {
        path = uri.getPath();
    } else if (scheme != null) {
        // handle non-file sources
        nativeSetDataSource(
            MediaHTTPService.createHttpServiceBinderIfNecessary(path),
            path,
            keys,
            values);
        return;
    }
```

`MediaPlayer` [uses](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#L1079) `MediaHTTPService` class, [which is responsible](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/media/java/android/media/MediaHTTPService.java#L34) for providing data from `http`, `https` and `widevine` protocols. `MediaHTTPService` internally uses [`MediaHTTPConnection`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/media/java/android/media/MediaHTTPConnection.java#L42), which takes all the heavy lifting for working with that type of streams. Unfortunately, these APIs are not public (yet), but you can see how connection establishing is done in [`MediaHTTPConnection`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/media/java/android/media/MediaHTTPConnection.java#L42) sources (particularly [`seekTo` method](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/media/java/android/media/MediaHTTPConnection.java#L170)). So, the custom data source that you provide to `MediaPlayer` should depict approximately the logics, that [`MediaHTTPConnection`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/media/java/android/media/MediaHTTPConnection.java#L42) class implements.

Comment: Thankyou for the attention. Your guess about `getSize()` to return -1 is fair, but it does not solve the problem (the LogCat trace is the same in this case). The main point is that the `MediaPlayer` _does_ playback **audio/mpeg** (both ways - through URL and through custom `MediaDataSource`), but **audio/aacp** streams could be played back _only_ via URL as DataSource... I just don't know where to dig anymore..

Comment: I see what you mean. Updated with a little bit more info.

Comment: I thought, I could bypass this "bug" (or "feature" or "phenomenon", nevermind) by using `MediaCodec`+`AudioTrack` instead of `MediaPlayer`, but goddamn android does not let me do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288285/mediaextractor-does-not-understand-audio-aacp-streams :(

Comment: I'ts not a "bug". I just ignored the `position` argument at `readAt()` and not allowed the `MediaExtractor` (or whatever `MediaPlayer` use) to skip the stream )