# Retrieve radio song titles from axWindowsMediaPlayer control

Tags: audio-streaming, icecast, shoutcast, axwindowsmediaplayer, webradio

I am am using the [AxWindowsMediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwindowsmediaplayer-object--vb-and-c) control to build a small Windows web radio developed in `C#`.

[image]

This works out well. My `StatusChange` event handler extracts the name of the current radio station:

```
    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_StatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IWMPMedia cm = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia;

        if (cm != null)
        {
            title = cm.getItemInfo("Title");
        }
    }
```

To polish up my radio, I would like to display additional information like name and artist of the current song. Such `StreamTitle` meta-data is shown by audio players like [mpg123](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpg123).

Example:

```
ICY-META: StreamTitle='Der Langmut der SPD mit Sarrazin hat nicht geholfen, Jürgen Zurheide';
```

Provided, a radio stream actually includes meta-information ([Icecast](https://superuser.com/questions/1069121/catch-metadata-from-icecast-audio-stream), [SHOUTcast](http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_XML_Metadata_Specification)):

> **Is there a way to get hold of radio stream titles using [AxWindowsMediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwindowsmediaplayer-object--vb-and-c)?**

I would not like the idea of a second thread digesting the whole stream just to extract the meta-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no easy way to extract [SHOUTCast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426483/how-do-i-obtain-shoutcast-now-playing-metadata-from-the-stream)/[Icecast](https://superuser.com/questions/1069121/catch-metadata-from-icecast-audio-stream) meta-data from [AxWindowsMediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwindowsmediaplayer-object--vb-and-c).

My solution is to replace [AxWindowsMediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwindowsmediaplayer-object--vb-and-c) by [BASS.NET](http://bass.radio42.com/).

[BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) is an audio library wrapped by [BASS.NET](http://bass.radio42.com/index.html) for [.Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/) usage.
It provides a `TAG_INFO` class which covers more than enough tags.

Code snippet from a [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) `C#` sample `NetRadio.cs`

```
if ( BassTags.BASS_TAG_GetFromURL( _Stream, _tagInfo) )
{
    this.textBoxAlbum.Text = _tagInfo.album;
    this.textBoxArtist.Text = _tagInfo.artist;
    this.textBoxTitle.Text = _tagInfo.title;
    this.textBoxComment.Text = _tagInfo.comment;
    this.textBoxGenre.Text = _tagInfo.genre;
    this.textBoxYear.Text = _tagInfo.year;
}
```

Resulting radio:

[image]

One alternative could be to download and evaluate [status-json.xsl](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-trunk/server_stats/) files provided by some internet radio stream providers. But I haven't tried this path yet.