# How do I playback an audio stream (not by URL)?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, shoutcast, opensl

Say, I have an InputStream, providing audio/mpeg (or audio/aacp) - a Shoutcast radio.
Could somebody please show me a code example to playback such a stream?
I searched all over the internet, and it looks like the android.media.MediaPlayer can't playback a buffered stream. It can playback streams only via HTTP URL as DataSource.
Yes, there is a possibility to implement your own android.media.MediaDataSource and feed it to MediaPlayer.setDataSource(), but in case of audio/aacp the codec [could not initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424424/how-do-i-use-custom-android-media-mediadatasource-along-with-android-media-media).

Guess this could be done with [OpenSL ES](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/opensl-for-android.html), but still I haven't found any example which would perform decoding from InputStream (not from URL), and then play back the output..

---

Come on guys! Any sample snippet in `OpenSL ES` decoding an input byte array and sending it to the audio output. Please!
Only one condition - input audio format should be obtained from the input stream.
The only one manual I found on `OpenSL ES` is [Khronos OpenSL ES™ Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenSL-ES/), but that is not a reading for beginners at all. I'd rather die there searching for a proper "how-to" example... :(

Why is it so weird - it's *very* simple /though inconvenient/ (java), or it's *very* hard (NDK)? Why is there nothing in the middle?

Comment: "I searched all over the internet, and it looks like the android.media.MediaPlayer can't playback a buffered stream" -- that is because the media playback is running in a separate process from yours. Your `MediaDataSource` approach would seem to be the right one. Since the source code for Android is available, compare how you are using the URL to how Android itself would use it (if you handed the URL over directly).

Comment: @CommonsWare Internally, MediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL) calls a private native function nativeSetDataSource(MediaHTTPService.createHttpServiceBinderIfNecessary(path), path, keys, values); (Path contains URL; Keys and Values contain HTTP Request Header's data). So, there is no way to look inside..

Answer (score 0):

your solution is something like this:

```
    public void run() {
        int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        AudioTrack atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 11025, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        atrack.setPlaybackRate(11025);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
        atrack.play();
        while (isPlaying) {
            yourStream.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
            atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wait. Even though my InputStream contains - for example - sequence of MP3 frames, there is no need to decode it? Just write to the AudioTrack? I thought I should write already decoded PCM to it, not the raw source..